# How to plot linestring geometry with R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, r-sf

I can do this if I go through `ggplotly()` first:

```
rivers <- RCzechia::reky("Brno")
p <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = rivers)
ggplotly(p)
```

But when I try the same thing with `plot_ly()`, it only displays a straight line:

```
plot_ly() %>% add_sf(data = rivers, type = "scatter")
```

What do I need to do for the second approach to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the data to sf coordinates and used the `ggplotly` you built to capture the aspect ratio.

```
plt <- ggplotly(p)

newRiver <- sf::st_coordinates(rivers) %>% as.data.frame(). # help plotly understand
plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "lines",
        x = ~X, y = ~Y, split = ~L1, data = newRiver) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(scaleratio = plt$x$layout$xaxis$scaleratio,  # set aspect ratio
                      scaleanchor = "y"))
```

[image]

Comment: This brought up new challenges as I need to combine the river linestring with other data, and this simple transformation deforms it (so rivers look ok but the rest doesn't). I will raise a separate question for that.